# Category-theoretical notion of logarithm

Tags: category-theory, logarithms, exponentiation, universal-property

The category-theoretic notion of an [exponential](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object) gives, as a special case, the usual exponentiation operation.

Considering that logarithm is the inverse of exponentiation, is there an analogous category-theoretic generalisation of the notion of logarithm?

Comment: Well, we could write $\log_AC=B$ when $C\cong A^B$, but this doesn't necessarily define an operation, because there might be objects $A,C$ such that $C\not\cong A^B$ for any $B$, or $C\cong A^B\cong A^{B'}$ for nonisomorphic $B,B'$. You can find such examples in $Set$.

Comment: @Berci Well, of course log is a multivalued function with restricted domain :)

Comment: > doesn't necessarily define an operation

I guess my question was: are there any interesting examples of categories in which this does define an operation?